# what are the global constants and functions avaliable in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I am new to drupal and i want to know the global constants and functions available in drupal like in Wordpress. It will be cool if there is functions like is_home or is_page, similar to  wordpress, which i can use in my theme.I tried  if($is_front) in my theme but it is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/globals for a list of globals defined in Drupal. In addition to globals variables, *local* variables are available in the various template fiel. For instance, in the [`page.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--page.tpl.php/6) template, the variable $is_front is defined. Variables available in template files are [set in template preprocess functions](http://drupal.org/node/223430) provided by modules and theme (usually in the template.php file).

If your are working on themes, you should check the [Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme).

Answer (score 0):

I know paper book aren't terribly popular anymore, but [Pro Drupal Development](http://www.drupalbook.com/) is pretty invaluable for outlining the API.

As far a variables go:

```
<?php
print_r(array_keys(get_defined_vars()));
?>
```

is a big start when you are inside a template file.